# How to draw "shapes" in python shell?

Tags: python

For example:

```
Enter the character you want to use to draw your square: *
Enter the width of your square: (insert value here)
Enter the height of your square: (insert value here)

*****
*****
*****
```

then it should produce an image that is somewhat like the one above.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry I am fairly new to this site. I'll take that into account next time.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to read over [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using single-nested loops, multiplying a string, and the usage of the `input` function.

```
char = input("Enter the character you want to use to draw your square: ")
width = int(input("Enter the width of your square: (insert value here): "))
height = int(input("Enter the height of your square: (insert value here): "))

for h in range(0,height):
    print(char * width)
```

There is an even more efficient way of printing the desired shape in terms of code and time, involving just one line. Replace the loop with this line:

```
print("\n".join([char * width for _ in range(height)]))
```

Here is a test run of my program. The first way using a loop took `11908` microseconds, the second took just `4998` microseconds.

```
Enter the character you want to use to draw your square: %
Enter the width of your square: (insert value here): 10
Enter the height of your square: (insert value here): 3
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: `line = char * width` would also work, and be more efficient

Comment: @jedwards Thanks. The edit states the existance of the more naive double-nested version

Comment: More efficient: `"\n".join(char * width for _ in range(height))`

Comment: If you made that a list comprehension inside join -- e.g. `"\n".join([char * width for _ in range(height)])` -- instead of a generator expression, even more profit.  (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/736937) from Python developer Raymond Hettinger).

Comment: @jedwards Thanks for providing a more efficient alternative. I wonder why is `join` more efficient than loops?

Comment: Appending to strings doesn't *really* append (strings are immutable, blah blah).  It creates a *new* string and reassigns the output variable to it.  Long loops will create many strings that will be used only once (the next iteration) and thrown away.  `join()` is more efficient in that it will create a single string of appropriate length, then fill in the characters as necessary.  Now 14 years old, [this site](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/) benchmarked different string concatenation methods.  You may try experimenting with them on your own if interested.